# Unable to display Spotify Play Button iframe as list on my Tumblr

Tags: css, iframe, tumblr, spotify

I am trying to embedded a Spotify Play Button iframe on a tumblr post. But the view as list would never work :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIIJQ.png

So I have managed to hide the buggy black zone with this :

```
    jQuery("main.css").ready(function() {
            jQuery("iframe.spotify_audio_player").parents('div.video-wrapper').css("padding-bottom", "11.2%");
    });
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpFEh.png

Apparently the problem is from a style attribute in the iframe but I can't find where is it set (probably by the API itself, but if it is really the case, I won't be able to do anything right ?). See how it looks in the Chrome Developer tool "Elements" :

```
<body data-urlencoded-name="hymced" class="regular index-page top" screen_capture_injected="true">
  <section id="page">
    <section id="posts" class="content clearfix no-image  avatar-style-hidden">
      <div data-page-id="1">
        <article class="video not-page post-95365069278" data-post-id="post_95365069278">
          <div class="post-wrapper clearfix">
            <section class="post">                        
              <figure>
                <div class="video-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 11.2%;">

                  <iframe id="oceanicplaylist" class="spotify_audio_player" src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=https://play.spotify.com/user/hymced/playlist/0LGSOwdwtRaXIrFaImOKx5" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" view="list" style="height: 80px;"></iframe>

                  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery("main.css").ready(function() {
                      jQuery("iframe.spotify_audio_player").parents('div.video-wrapper').css("padding-bottom", "11.2%");
                    });
                  </script>

                </div>    
              </figure>
            </section>
          </div>
        </article>  
      </div>
    </section>
  </section>
</body>
```

Here is what's messing around :

```
style="height: 80px;"
```

This parameter is not the the inline html code, nor in any main.css stylesheet. But when forcing it to width of post + 80px = 782px in the Developer tool, it works.

Answer (score 0):

IN order to set a Spotify Play Button iframe on tumblr **you must**

1) Open Spotify and right click on the Album, Track or Playlist you would like to embed.

2) Click on “Copy Embed Code”

3) Paste this code in your blog or website in the HTML editor view.
 LINK BELOW!!!

```
  http://cf.scdn.co/u/wp/Screen-Shot-2012-08-15-at-2.00.57-PM1.png
```

4) That’s it!

O yeah

- To change the height and the width of the play button, just edit these two fields:
  width="250" height="300"
  (Minimum width is 250 pixels, minimum height is 80 pixels)
- To have the Play Button with a white theme, just add “&theme=white” right after the playlist or album code:

spotify:user:spotify:playlist:6AV1SULGwX3OFyYzoZqokN&theme=white"

- If you prefer to show the cover art view, add “&view=coverart” after the playlist or album code:

spotify:user:spotify:playlist:6AV1SULGwX3OFyYzoZqokN&theme=white&view=coverart"

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: Sorry but no it does not help. This does not work when posting (which I am trying to do, and not put it in the HTML directly). That's the problem here